# Using urllib3 with python 2.7 to download .txt file from url?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, shutil, urllib3

I'm using Python 2.7, and I have urllib3.  I'm trying to download each of the .txt files in this link: http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3, shutil


http = urllib3.PoolManager()

MTA_url = requests.get("http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html").text
MTA_soup = BeautifulSoup(MTA_url)
#Find each link to be downloaded
MTA_soup.findAll('a')
#Let's test it with the 36th link
one_a_tag = MTA_soup.findAll("a")[36]
MTA_link = one_a_tag["href"]

download_url = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/'+ MTA_link
print download_url #valid url, will take you to download
```

This is where I'm stuck. I can't seem to figure out how to download the .txt file at `download_url`, let alone iterate through the list. I've tried this:

```
open('/Users/me/Documents/test_output_download.csv', 'wb').write(download_url.content)
```

But that gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'content'
```

After reading further, I also tried:

```
out_file = '/Users/me/Documents/test_output_download.csv'
http.request('GET', download_url, preload_content=False) as res, open(out_file, 'wb') as out_file:
   shutil.copyfileobj(res, out_file)
```

But I get past this syntax error:

```
    http.request('GET', download_url, preload_content=False) as res, open(out_file, 'wb') as out_file:
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I just download the .txt file that is located at `download_url` and save it to my local drive, using urllib3?

Comment: There was probably a `with` you didn't notice in the source you read.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you’re using Python 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'as' keyword is used for imports. I tested the full segment of code and was able to download after making a small change here.

Try shifting this around to declare the objects to variables instead, like so:

```
res = http.request('GET', download_url, preload_content=False)

out_file = open(out_file, 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(res, out_file)
```

Comment: It's used for imports, but it's also used for exception handling and for `with` statements. The code in the question looks like a mangled `with` statement.

Comment: ThomThio - Thank you!  This worked.  I don't understand why the whole shutil.copyfileobj is needed - why wouldn't something simpler such as this work instead? : open('/Users/me/Documents/test_output_download.csv', 'wb').write(download_url.content)

Comment: Well you need to break that line into its components.

download_url is a string - there isnt any results behind this (such as content), until the http.request is called via 
**res = http.request('GET', download_url, preload_content=False)**

Thereafter, "res" is holding a csv so-to-speak - its not a string where you can write it line by line into your desired file. Therefore you need shutil.copyfileobj to read it sequentially and write it into the known file format for you.

Comment: For clarity, @user2357112supportsMonica is referring to another way to call the opening of files, it would work if you add a **with** in front of the declaration too.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation makes sense.